# Limitar opções de pagamento apenas a contas PayPal (cartão de crédito não)

Tags: php

Estou a fazer a integração da API PayPal Express Checkout.

Quando o pagante efectivamente vai para o site da Paypal para introdução dos seus dados de forma a realizar o pagamento, são-lhe apresentadas as seguintes opções:

[image: Captura de Tela]

- Pagamento com conta PayPal
- Pagamento através de Cartão de Crédito

## Problema

Nesta integração em particular, os pagamentos a realizar via PayPal deverão estar limitados a contas PayPal, ou seja, a opção do cartão de crédito deve ficar indisponível ou não aparecer por completo.

[Na documentação da API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> não encontrei nenhuma referência a este assunto nem opção para indicar que não pretendo que a opção do cartão de crédito seja apresentada.

#### Parâmetros enviados para a API

Na função em baixo, são preparados os diversos parâmetros que indicam à API o que é pretendido que seja apresentado ao pagante bem como o layout da página no lado da PayPal:

```php
/**
 * CALL SHORTCUT EXPRESS CHECKOUT
 *
 * Prepares the parameters for the SetExpressCheckout API Call.
 *
 * @param string $token             Internal security token
 * @param string $cartLinesArr      The cart lines to build the url string.
 * @param string $cartTotalsArr     The cart products and delivery total.
 *
 * @return array                    Response array from Paypal
 */
public function callShortcutExpressCheckout($token, $cartLinesArr, $cartTotalsArr) {

  //get all details about this transaction
  $transactionArr = $this->getClientData($cartTotalsArr);

  /*
   * Buyers Address and Contacts
   */
  $shiptoAddress = "&SHIPTONAME="        . urlencode($transactionArr["firstName"]." ".$transactionArr["lastName"]);
  $shiptoAddress.= "&SHIPTOSTREET="      . urlencode($transactionArr["address"]);
  $shiptoAddress.= "&SHIPTOSTREET2="     . urlencode($transactionArr["address2"]);
  $shiptoAddress.= "&SHIPTOCITY="        . urlencode($transactionArr["city"]);
  $shiptoAddress.= "&SHIPTOSTATE="       . urlencode($transactionArr["state"]);
  $shiptoAddress.= "&SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=" . urlencode($transactionArr["countryCode"]);
  $shiptoAddress.= "&SHIPTOZIP="         . urlencode($transactionArr["zipCode"]);
  $shiptoAddress.= "&SHIPTOPHONENUM="    . urlencode($transactionArr["contact"]);

  /*
   * Cart Items
   */
  $PAYPAL_CART_ITEMS = "";
  $c = 0;

  if ($cartLinesArr) {

    foreach ($cartLinesArr as $cartLine) {

      $PAYPAL_CART_ITEMS.= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER" . $c . "=" . urlencode($cartLine["id"]);
      $PAYPAL_CART_ITEMS.= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME"   . $c . "=" . urlencode($cartLine["name"]);
      $PAYPAL_CART_ITEMS.= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"    . $c . "=" . urlencode($cartLine["price"]);
      $PAYPAL_CART_ITEMS.= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY"    . $c . "=" . urlencode($cartLine["quantity"]);
      $c++;
    }
  }

  /*
   * Construct the parameter string that describes the
   * SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation
   */
  $nvpstr = "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT="           . urlencode(numberFormat($transactionArr["shippingVal"]+$transactionArr["chargeValue"]));
  $nvpstr.= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT="       . urlencode($transactionArr["chargeValue"]);
  $nvpstr.= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT="   . urlencode($transactionArr["shippingVal"]);
  $nvpstr.= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" . urlencode(PAYPAL_PAYMENT_TYPE);
  $nvpstr.= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE="  . urlencode(PAYPAL_CURRENCY_CODE_TYPE);
  $nvpstr.= "&RETURNURL="                      . urlencode(PAYPAL_RETURN_URL.$token);
  $nvpstr.= "&CANCELURL="                      . urlencode(PAYPAL_CANCEL_URL.$token);
  $nvpstr.= "&ADDRESSOVERRIDE=1";
  $nvpstr.= $shiptoAddress;
  $nvpstr.= "&ALLOWNOTE="                      . urlencode(PAYPAL_ALLOWNOTE);
  $nvpstr.= "&HDRIMG="                         . urlencode(PAYPAL_USE_LOGOTYPE);
  $nvpstr.= "&LOCALECODE="                     . urlencode(PAYPAL_LOCAL_CODE);
  $nvpstr.= "&EMAIL="                          . urlencode($transactionArr["email"]);
  $nvpstr.= $PAYPAL_CART_ITEMS;
  $nvpstr.= "&LANDINGPAGE="                    . urlencode(PAYPAL_LANDING_PAGE);
  $nvpstr.= "&NOTETOBUYER="                    . urlencode(I18N_ESHOP_PAYPAL_NOTES);


  /*
   * Make the API call to PayPal
   */
  return $this->hash_call("SetExpressCheckout", $nvpstr);
}
```

## Pergunta

Como passar um parâmetro para a API da PayPal de forma a que a mesma limite as opções de pagamento que são apresentadas ao pagante, onde só é pretendido aceitar pagamentos via contas PayPal?

Comment: quando vc "Paga com cartão" no paypal, ele solicita email e senha, criando uma conta para o usuário, ou não é assim mais?

Comment: @hernandes Presumo que ainda seja dessa forma, mas a questão aqui é: Pagamentos com Cartão de Crédito tem uma taxa elevada e o meu cliente pretende, nesses casos, recorrer a outra solução que não a PayPal. Contudo, como muito potencial cliente tem conta na PayPal, ele pretende aceitar esses pagamentos de conta-paypal para conta-paypal.

Comment: mas após logar, ainda existe a possibilidade de pagar com Cartão de crédito, após logado

Comment: acredito que o Paypal não ofereça essas condições, veja em https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/admin/setup-account/#id095FF4006HS

Comment: @hernandes Isso com "Express CheckOut" ? O pagante vai do web-site para a Paypal, identifica-se paga e é "xutado" para o web-site novamente... Se passar indicação que ele não pode usar Cartão de Crédito, só fica com hipótese de pagar com dinheiro na sua conta-paypal. Penso que sanamos a questão num todo (se existir efectivamente tal parâmetro ou forma de controlar isto)!

Comment: @hernandes Obrigado por esse link, estive a ler e deu dicas para realizar pesquisas sobre o assunto _de outra forma..._ Estou a ver se encontro mais informação!

Comment: Na Api SetExpressCheckout basta adicionar: `solutiontype=mark`

Answer (score 3):

O Paypal não permite tal bloqueio, os únicos bloqueios disponíveis são:

- Bloquear pagamentos de Pessoas dos Estados Unidos sem endereço de email confirmado
- Bloquear pagamentos em moedas que não as da sua conta
- Bloquear pagamentos acidentais (mesmo número de fatura ser paga mais de uma vez)
- Bloquear pagamentos de pessoas com contas Paypal que não sejam dos Estados Unidos
- Bloquear pagamentos enviados de forma avulsa ("Enviar dinheiro a alguem")
- Bloquear pagamentos via eCheck

Seria uma bom recurso a ser adicionado

Fonte: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/admin/setup-account/#id095FF500A4Y